# Opening help frame with F1 key

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

How can I open Help frame with F1 not using menus even though menus request key combinations? I tried with `KeyListener`, adding a key listener to panel that calls Help frame something like:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            Help obj = new Help();
            getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
            obj.setVisible(true);
            obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       }
},
```

I used up key because I don't know F1 key code, but from what I searched panels don't work with key listener since they are not focusable. So how can I achieve it?

#### Image below shows help panel

[image: Image below shows help panel]

Comment: you may want to look into keyBindings, if you are using swing: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: `KeyEvent.VK_F1`, like you'd expect if the UP key has VK_UP.